# Integrate FileSystemWatcher code in BackgroundWorker to avoid GUI freeze

Tags: vb.net

I have an application similar to an anti-spyware program. I use a list of MD5 hashes to detect infected files. I also use a FileSystemWatcher to watch and monitor newly renamed, created, changed files on a computer.
However, using a FileSystemWatcher will freeze the GUI as soon as the application is started, so I may need to integrate my FileSystemWatcher code into a BackgroundWorker to avoid GUI freezing.
The question is how to achieve that objective ?
Thanks in advance.

My FileSystemWatcher code is as follows:

```
 Private Sub FileSystemWatcher1_Changed(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles FileSystemWatcher1.Changed
  Try

        Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
        Dim scanbox As New TextBox
        scanbox.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\virusdb.txt").ToString
        Dim md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
        Dim f As New FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, &H2000)
        f.Close()
        f = New FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, &H2000)
        md5.ComputeHash(f)
        Dim hash As Byte() = md5.Hash
        Dim buff As New StringBuilder
        Dim hashByte As Byte
        For Each hashByte In hash
            buff.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", hashByte))
        Next
        f.Close()
        If scanbox.Text.Contains(buff.ToString) Then
            Labellastreal.Text = e.FullPath
            realtimelistbox.Items.Add(Labellastreal.Text)
            Me.OpenFileDialog2.FileName = e.FullPath
            Form2.ShowDialog()

        Else

            Labellastreal.Text = e.FullPath
            realtimelistbox.Items.Add(Labellastreal.Text)

        End If

    Catch exception As Exception
        ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception)
        Dim ex As Exception = exception
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
    End Try
```

- I use the same above code for FileSystemWatcher1_Renamed and FileSystemWatcher1_Created

Comment: Performance tip: Use a `HashSet`, or better yet: a Bloom Filter.

Comment: How do I do that with my code ?

Comment: Drop a `BackgroundWorker` on your form, then from your `FileSystemWatcher1.Changed` event, call the [RunWorkerAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync?view=netcore-3.1) method.  Pass or store any necessary information at Form level, then put your code in the [DoWork()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork?view=netcore-3.1) event.

Comment: I did, it gives me an error  at  "e.fullpath" as follows : "FullPath is not a member of DoWorkEventArgs" meaning that since I added the code into the backgroundworker, it doesn't see the filesystemwatcher's path anymore, how to fix that ?

Comment: The FileSystemWatcher events are not raised in the UI Thread. So you either have set the Synchronizing object, then just don't, or you have disabled Cross Threading violations exceptions, otherwise `Form2.ShowDialog()` would throw. -- The most important thing is that you must not block the FSW events in any way (let's not event talk about a Modal Dialog). It's the processing that comes after that must be handed over to a worker thread - to avoid blocking the events. The UI is not touched up to this point. When you need to marshal updates to the UI Thread, do it from the worker thread.

Comment: To move element for processing to the worker *thread* (possibly a long-running Task), you can use a [ConcurrentQueue<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) or something similar: enqueue new work items and let the worker thread process them as they come in.